# How to setup vscode C++ intellisense to use gcc compiler?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, vscode-extensions

I'm using C++ in vscode with Microsoft C/C++ Extension. I'm using g++ compiler provided in msys2:

```
gcc --version
gcc.exe (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0
```

When I write this code in editor, it shows error squiggles:

```
*std::ranges::find(myvec, foo1) = foo2;
 ~~~
```

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::ranges::__find_fn::operator()" matches the argument list C/C++(304)
mycode.cpp(122, 3): argument types are: (std::vector<const Foo *, std::allocator<const Foo *>>, const Foo *)
mycode.cpp(122, 3): object type is: const std::ranges::__find_fn
```

But, when I compile this file with `-std=c++23`, it compiles properly, even without any warnings.

My C/C++ configuration looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-std=c++23"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "cStandard": "c23",
            "cppStandard": "c++23"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

How do I resolve these errors?